# I want to know about spring hateoas

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on spring boot. I don't know what is **spring hateoas** why we go for spring hateoas.

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/accounts/{id}/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Resource<AccountHolder> findAccountHolderById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @PathVariable("userId") int i) {
        logger.info("accounts findAccountHolderById() invoked: " + id);
        Account account = accountRepository.getAccount(id.toString());
        AccountHolder accountHolder = account.getAccountHolder();
        Resource<AccountHolder> resource = new Resource<AccountHolder>(accountHolder);
        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(AccountController.class).byId(account.getAccountId())).withRel("account"));
        logger.info("accounts findAccountHolderById() found: " + account);
        return resource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HATEOAS means that a REST webservice not only provides the answer you asked for (e.g. the account) but also links to related data like the customer or subaccounts of that account. You can also provide links to actions like "disable account". That way the clients can navigate through the data more easily.

See https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS

P.S.: When copy & pasting code, use the "{}" symbol in the edit box to format it correctly.